# Equivalence conditions in the Heine-Borel theorem for the real line

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

The Heine Borel theorem ([book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433314), pg 335) shows that the following conditions are equivalent-

1. A set $K$ is closed and bounded.
2. $K$ is compact.

My question is that in the proof of 1 $\implies$ 2 where has the condition that $K$ is closed been used ?

*The proof for  1 $\implies$ 2 in the book is reproduced below,*

Consider a family of open sets $\mathcal{G}$ that cover $K$. Assume that $K$ is not compact. Therefore, there does not exist a finite sub-cover of $K$ in $\mathcal{G}$.

Also assume 1. Now by assumption there exists a number $r$ such that $I_0 = [-r,r] \supset K$. Divide the set $I_0$ into two halfs, ${I_0}^\prime = [-r,0]$ and ${I_0}^{\prime\prime} = [0,r]$. Now since $K$ is not compact atleast one of $K \cap {I_0}^{\prime\prime}$ and $K \cap {I_0}^{\prime}$ must be non-empty  and and not contained in a finite number of sets in $\mathcal{G}$. Let $I_1 = {I_0}^{\prime}$ if $K \cap {I_0}^{\prime}$ and does not have a finite cover in $\mathcal{G}$ otherwise $I_1 = {I_0}^{\prime\prime}$. Now divide $I_1$ into two parts and continue in the same fashion.

Each interval $I_n$ contains infinitely many points in $K$. Let $z \in \cap_n I_n$. Therefore $z$ is a cluster point of $K$. There exists a set $G_\lambda \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $z \in G_\lambda$. Since $G_\lambda$ is open we must have $(z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon) \in G_\lambda$. Also, since each $I_n$ contains $z$ and the size of $I_n$ decreases exponentially with $n$, $\exists N$ such that $I_N \subset (z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon) \subset G_\lambda $ . But this means that $I_N$ is contained in a single set in $\mathcal{G}$. Since $N$ is finite, we can cover $K$ in this fashion with finite sets in $\mathcal{G}$. But this leads to a contradiction. Therefore, $K$ cannot be compact.

Comment: "Let $z \in \cap_n I_n \subset K$. " What insures this?

Comment: @DavidMitra edited. the above condition is ensured by the nested intervals property (see book)

Comment: @DavidMitra corrected both the things

Comment: Ok. So the point is, $z$ is a cluster point of $K$. But closed sets contain their cluster points. In my edition (third), this is Theorem 11.1.8.